# Hapi js cookie TTL showing different value on the browser

Tags: javascript, cookies, hapi.js

When I set the TTL of the cookie value from the Hapi-node server the cookie is getting created , but the ttl value looks different.

[image]

```
 let _isSecure = false;  
 let _options = {  
 ttl: 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000,         
 isSecure: _isSecure,       
 isHttpOnly: false,
  path: '/',   
  encoding: 'none'
 };     
return reply(res).state('SESSION-ID', res.responseHeaders['SESSION-ID'], _options)
```

Answer (score 0):

You provived the time to live as one day and the browser shows the date and time when the page will actually expire which is in one day.

Comment: when the cookie is set on the browser , the values looks to be more than 24hrs expiry time...Please find the attached image in the question